# Change date format inside HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code on a page:

```
<span class="release-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 2014-11-16</span>
```

This `2014-11-16` is the date and is generated automatically by my CMS. I need to change this date. Basically I need to change the month to read differently because this site has an international audience. In the case above I want it to read like this: `2014-Nov-16`.

I know this can be done using a RegEx, however, I have no idea how to write this RegEx as I am not good at them. Of course in my example above 11 = Nov, 12 would equal Dec and so on for each month.

Comment: You shouldn't use regex. Select the element and change it's text content.

Comment: @Vohuman - Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I posted an answer but then realized maybe you don't want Javascript.  Where are you trying to fix these dates?  Client side or server side?  And if it's server side, what language is the server written in?

Comment: @mrrogers - Client Side so JS is what I am after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a snippets with jQuery and [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) that does what you want, I made format into a variable so you can play with is.

```js
$('.release-date').each( function() {
  
  var format = "Do MMM YYYY";

  var $this = $( this );
  var old_date = $.trim($this.text());
  var new_date = moment(old_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD').format( format );

  $this.text($this.text().replace(old_date, new_date));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="release-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 2014-11-16</span>
```

Comment: @Lynda It [supports locales](http://momentjs.com/#multiple-locale-support) as well

Comment: Interesting. How would I include locales if I wanted to the example above?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Javascript `Date` to save you some ugly regex

```
new Date("2014-11-16")
>> Sat Nov 15 2014 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
new Date("2014-11-16 PST")
>> Sun Nov 16 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Unless you add another library like [momemt.js](http://momentjs.com/) or something, you may need to add a little helper to get the month as a string.  Something like:

```
function monthToString(month) {
  var months = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', ... , 'Dec' ];
  return months[month % months.length]
}
```

Then you can build the new date string like this

```
function convertDateString(dateFromCms) {
   var date = new Date(dateFromCms);
   return date.getFullYear() + "-" + monthToString(date.getMonth()) + "-" + date.getDate();
}
```

Or something along those lines.  Check out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more about how `Date` works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/sg8rt6h7/1/)

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('release-date')[0];
var text = elem.innerHTML;
var regex = /-(\d{1,2})-/m
var month = regex.exec(text);
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

if (month[1]) {
    elem.innerHTML = text.replace(regex, "-" + months[parseInt(month[1], 10) - 1] + "-")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the `textNode` of the span elements, you can iterate through their `childNode`s and filter the `textNode`:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.release-date'), function(el) {
    var n = el.childNodes, inputDate;

    for ( var i = n.length; i--; ) {
        if ( n[i].nodeType === 3 && n[i].nodeValue.trim().length ) {
              inputDate = n[i].nodeValue.trim();
              n[i].nodeValue = // modify the input date        
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too..

```
var months = {
  1: 'jan',
  2: 'feb',
  3: 'march',
  4: 'apr',
  5: 'may',
  6: 'june',
  7: 'july',
  8: 'aug',
  9: 'sep',
  10: 'oct',
  11: 'nov',
  12: 'dec'
};

var currentDate = "2014-11-16"; // your date string would go here. Note, I left the retrieval of it out. This is trivial w/ jQuery... $('.release-date').text();

var redrawnCurrentDate = currentDate.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/,function(_,$1,$2){
    return months[$1] + "-" + $2;
});

$('.release-date').text(redrawnCurrentDate);
```