# javascript replace string after matching line

Tags: javascript, regex

I expected to find an answer to a typical problem with regular expressions.

- Find a given line
- Change something on that line

Many examples of how to use RegEx replace assume you know the pattern you want to replace.  Great for teaching but not typical (IMO).  See [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).  If it is on the MDN page please point it out.

In my latest problem, I have an html file that has uniq IDs on a line so I can perform this simple replacement.   The syntax of the lines I need modified are shown below.  I can place a unique string in the file so I can find the correct line to update.

```
<span id="lastModified">2018-10-26</span>
<span id="builtBy">Pat</span>
```

I need to find the line that has `id="lastModified"` and change the date.

I need to find the line that has `id="builtBy"` and change the date.

I tried a few different things.  One is

```
var res = str.replace(/id="lastModified".*>(.*)<.span>/, newDate );
```

I thought the default might be to change the data matched in the parens (nope it doesn't work that way).  See [JSFiddle code example](https://jsfiddle.net/PatS2265/571mpcya/16/) of what I tried that didn't work.

*NOTE: In my case I'm trying to figure this out because for a simple string replacement using gulp-replace but it's really a javascript pattern matching and replacement problem so I'm not bring gulp-replace into this question other than to mention it.*

*NOTE: In my case, this code is not executing in the browser, so typical DOM manipulation will not work.*

Other questions that I found (but didn't answer my question) were:

- [How can I use gulp to replace a string in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243881/how-can-i-use-gulp-to-replace-a-string-in-a-file)
- [Change date format inside HTML with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963948/change-date-format-inside-html-with-javascript)
- [JavaScript RegExp Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230010/javascript-regexp-replace)

Comment: In general, better to use DOM traversal when possible instead of regex.

Comment: Also, if you want to use a regular expression, pass a regular expression to `.replace`, not a string

Comment: **(?!lastModified)[^\>]+(?=\<)** this will match the date, and then, you can change it. (Works on regex101 tho: https://regex101.com/r/kA2kAG/1)

Comment: what's your execution environment? - describe what hosts the code need to replace the element's value (e.g. code will run inside `gulp` / `webpack` / 'browser')

Comment: @CertainPerformance, This is part of a build process not running in browser so DOM is not available in node (using gulp).

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thanks for pointing that out.  I updated my question to use the regex //, syntax instead of a string.

Comment: Here is one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlparser. Another one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dom. One for Node - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match your first line:

```
/(<span id="lastModified">)(.*?)(</span>)/
```

It basically matches literally the text and captures it in three Groups, which is then used in the replacement pattern, which can be:

```
$12018-10-26$3
```

First it replaces with `$1` (the first matched Group), then your date (which you will want to come from a variable) and finally `$3` which is the end span.

Comment: Thanks @Poul Bak, this is the answer I came up.  So the final code is
```var res = str.replace(/(<span id="lastModified">)(.*?)(</span>)/, '$12018-1026$3');```